# Alignment problem, stacking

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

[image]

Hello, everyone!

Numberphile has this great video on Euler's constant, and I would like to replicate one of the ways to get e.

So far I managed to come this far, but I don't know how to create the arrow and infinity under the n.

[image]

Please help me, thank you very much!

PS. I only have the base package of LaTeX.

Comment: I think the correct way is `\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}`, not just `n \to \infty` (all in math mode, of course)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You beat me by a few seconds to this comment. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Christian and Mico! I am quite new to LaTeX :-)

Comment: @Mico, well, finally I beat you in ... something. I bet, Steven will come up with some stacking ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can't you leave off the `\limits`, since `\lim` is already set up to underlay a subscript?  That is, `\lim_{n\to\infty}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: In displaymode, yes, of course. I was thinking about 'inline'

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes.  It is just that the fraction shown is also in `\displaystyle`, so I figured that was the mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: So true....

Answer (score 3):

The correct way for typing would be `\lim_{n\to\infty}` in displaystyle mode or `\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}` if not in displaystyle mode (the `\limits` command does no harm in displaystyle mode, however)

Please note the difference for the fraction as well, if not shown in displaystyle.

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$

\[\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've omitted the case for non-displaystyle... that does not look nice for `\lim` in my point of view

Answer (score 1):

This seems like `s`hort `h`and notation for `lim`its. Here's one options using a text-style fraction *without* a rule (thanks to `\genfrac`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\shlim}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}{#1}{\rightarrow #2}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \shlim{n}{\infty}
  \bigl( 1 + \tfrac{1}{n} \bigr)^n
\]

\end{document}
```

Using `\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}` seems more widely accepted though.